# Bootstrap method failing where blocking works

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, monte-carlo, means

I'm computing an average of individual samples that are not entirely independent and need an estimate for the true standard deviation. According to [Newman and Barkema's book](https://books.google.ie/books/about/Monte_Carlo_Methods_in_Statistical_Physi.html?id=J5aLdDN4uFwC&redir_esc=y) the most reliable method will be Bootstrap sampling (see section 3.4.3), where you don't have to worry about the samples being independent and which should give an estimate of the standard deviation of the mean $\sigma_m\approx\sigma\ /\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the number of samples.

However I proceed to compute the average a number of times so that I get a brute force estimate of the actual $\sigma_m$, and it turns out that the bootstrap is consistently underestimating this.

In itself that is maybe not so strange; the bootstrap being an estimate. But the weird thing is that if I use the blocking (or binning) method (see 3.4.2) I get a much better estimate - while according to Newman and Barkema this should be a much more primitive method.

In fact the bootstrap consistently gives an estimate very close to the naive $\sigma_m\approx\sqrt{\big(\ \overline{x^2}-\overline{x}^2\ \big)\ /\ n}$.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Bootstrap works for independent data and for correlated data, one cannot expect similar performance.

Comment: But considering Newman & Barkema, isn't it strange that blocking works so much better? And wouldn't you expect bootstrap to at least be better than the naive estimate?

Comment: Did you try different data?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Yeah, this happens with all my data.

Comment: Are you able to estimate the third moment (skewness) of your population (or of large samples)?

Comment: ... and fourth moment (kurtosis) either raw or central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive bootstrap method (where the original data is resampled with replacement) does indeed systematically underestimate the error of correlated data as discussed for example in [Remark 2.1 on page 1192 in A. Singh, The Annals of Statistics 9, 1187-1195](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240409).

I'm not at all an expert in this field, and came across the same problem as the original poster, also following the book by Newman and Barkema. My interpretation after reading the original literature and playing with data is that the description in Newman and Barkema is rather misleading.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

Use "$n-1$".  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-in-n-1-when-calculating-sd .  If you use $n$ you have a biased estimator of the s.d.  Since $n> n-1$ the bias is negative (towards too small s.d.s).

I.e., use $\sigma_m \approx \sigma/\sqrt{n-1}$.

### Step 2

(Added by edit on 20150715, based on additional information from the poster.)

If the fourth (and/or higher even moments of the population distribution) are non-zero, then the sample s.d.s may be biased estimators of the population s.d.s.  (The biases from the various moments *could* cancel, but that's rare in practice.)

The distribution of sample standard deviations is distributed with mean equal to the population standard deviation and with variance $\frac{\mu_4}{n} - \frac{\mu_2^2(n-3)}{n(n-1)}$.  That is, the sample s.d. will systematically vary from the population s.d. if the fourth central moment of the population is not zero.  This deviation will decrease to zero as $1/n$.

Relative to bootstrapping, if your population distribution is leptokurtic (has excess kurtosis relative to the standard normal, equivalently, is more central with thinner tails than a normal distribution), and the initial sample is representative, then a subsample is likely to underestimate the population s.d.  If the population is platykurtic (low center, fat tails) and the initial sample is representative, then subsamples likely overestimate the population s.d.

Comment: for $n$ large, it will have almost no effect.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören : I find no evidence in the original post that $n$ is large in the cases the poster is concerned about.  In fact the poster observes that the discrepancy decreases as $n$ increases.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören :  It may help to read OP's other question on this issue.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143370/standard-deviation-of-the-mean-through-bootstrap-resampling-of-dependent-samples

Comment: I didnt mean that the answer is of no use. Just reminded that *if* the number of samples is large enough then probably the reason could be different

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is independent of $n$. (also: I had actually forgotten about that other question; the difference is that here I've noticed that blocking actually works, which is weird considering Newman & Barkema, in my opinion)

Comment: also, I don't use n in the bootstrap (only in the naive estimate)

Comment: I'm not entirely happy with the sentence "That is, the sample s.d. will systematically vary from the population s.d. if the fourth moment of the population is not zero."  Let's see if it's confusing to anyone...

Comment: This is very interesting, I will consider higher moments. Do you have any thoughts on whether this can explain why blocking still works?